# How to enable Dark Mode in all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a JS script and when a user presses the button that says Dark Mode the page switches to dark_theme.css (instead of using theme.css which is the Ligh Mode css) and when the user presses Light Mode button it switches back to theme.css. So my problem is that when a user uses darm_theme.css and loads a different page or refreshes the current page the theme switches back to light mode. How can I somehow save the user's selection/choice?

```js
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

```css
I have one file called theme.css and one more called dark_theme.css
```

```html
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
...more html here...
<p><button class="colormode" onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark_theme.css')">Dark Mode</button> <button class="colormode" onclick="swapStyleSheet('theme.css')">Light Mode</button></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use localStorage for that:

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
  document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', sheet);
  localStorage.setItem("sheet", sheet);
}

window.onload = _ =>
 swapStyleSheet(
  localStorage.getItem("sheet") || "default.css"
 );
```

Comment: Well this does work but only on the index.html and about.html pages which are on the same folder as the js and the 2 CSS files. It doesnt work on the other pages which are in subfolders.

Comment: @apost well you need absolute urls then. Thats not a problem of the code

Comment: How can I use absolute URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies. (Cookie functions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103596)

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    createCookie ("sheet", sheet);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var item = readCookie ("sheet") || "default.css";
    swapStyleSheet (item);
});
```